# Failure in compiling a Spring MVC project with Tomcat plugin

Tags: java, spring, gradle, tomcat

I am learning to create a Spring MVC project using Tomcat plugin (https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin). My project structure is as below:

```
[ jounPc.joun t2 ]::tree .
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── main
│   │           ├── META-INF
│   │           └── org
│   │               └── example
│   │                   ├── Main.class
│   │                   └── TestController.class
│   ├── generated
│   │   └── sources
│   │       ├── annotationProcessor
│   │       │   └── java
│   │       │       └── main
│   │       └── headers
│   │           └── java
│   │               └── main
│   ├── libs
│   │   ├── t2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.war
│   │   └── t2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
│   ├── resolvedMainClassName
│   └── tmp
│       ├── bootWar
│       │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│       ├── compileJava
│       │   ├── compileTransaction
│       │   │   ├── backup-dir
│       │   │   └── stash-dir
│       │   │       └── TestController.class.uniqueId0
│       │   └── previous-compilation-data.bin
│       ├── ssl
│       ├── tomcatRun
│       │   └── work
│       │       └── Tomcat
│       │           └── localhost
│       │               └── ROOT
│       └── war
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle.kts
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradleLog
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle.kts
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── org
    │   │       └── example
    │   │           ├── Main.java
    │   │           └── TestController.java
    │   ├── resources
    │   └── webapp
    │       └── WEB_INF
    │           ├── index.jsp
    │           ├── sample-servlet.xml
    │           └── web.xml
    └── test
        ├── java
        └── resources
```

And some of the files that I modified here

- `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.7.0")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("com.bmuschko.tomcat") version "2.7.0"
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
//    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:6.0.9")
    implementation("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1")
    implementation("org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper:10.1.10")

    val tomcatVersion = "9.0.73"
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}")
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}")
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:9.0.0.M6")
}

tomcat {
    httpProtocol = "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
    ajpProtocol  = "org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol"
    httpPort = 8080
    enableSSL = true
    contextPath = "/"
}
```

- `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID"
        version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>
    <absolute-ordering/>

    <!--  Spring MVC Configs  -->
    <!--  Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet  -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/sample-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!--  Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet  -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

- `sample-servlet.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!--  Step 3: Add support for component scanning  -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>

    <!--  Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!--  Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver  -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

- A simple controller `TestController.java`

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class TestController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String getInfo() {
    return "Test controller";
  }
}
```

The problem is while gradle had no problems building it, nor retrieving the dependencies, it fails when I executed the server with `tomcatRun`.

```
$ gradle tomcatRun --stacktrace > ./gradleLog

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tomcatRun'.
> An error occurred starting the Tomcat server.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':tomcatRun'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: An error occurred starting the Tomcat server.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.startTomcat(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat_closure3.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:234)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat_closure3.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.LoggingHandler.withJdkFileLogger(LoggingHandler.groovy:54)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.LoggingHandler$withJdkFileLogger.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.validateConfigurationAndStartTomcat(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:233)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_start_closure2.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:226)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun$_start_closure2.doCall(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.utils.TomcatThreadContextClassLoader.withClasspath(TomcatThreadContextClassLoader.groovy:30)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.utils.ThreadContextClassLoader$withClasspath.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.start(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:225)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[-genkey, -alias, localhost, -dname, CN=localhost,OU=Test,O=Test,C=US, ...]]
Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), any(), find(), wait(long, int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.ssl.SSLKeyStoreImpl.invokeKeyTool(SSLKeyStoreImpl.groovy:81)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.ssl.SSLKeyStoreImpl.createSSLCertificate(SSLKeyStoreImpl.groovy:52)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.internal.ssl.SSLKeyStore$createSSLCertificate.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.tasks.AbstractTomcatRun.startTomcat(AbstractTomcatRun.groovy:347)
        ... 129 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Is there any way or any keywords I can look for to resolve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

===

#### Specs

Gradle version: 8.1.1

Kotlin:       1.8.10

Groovy:       3.0.15

Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021

JVM:          20.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 20.0.1+9)

OS:           Linux 6.3.9-arch1-1 amd64

Comment: You are using SPring Boot why the tomcat plugin? You are using a Spring (BOot) version that is for JakartaEE, while you are shoehoring Tomcat 9 in there which is JavaEE. But as stated you shouldn't need that plugin anyway.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your info about the shoehoring, I had no idea about the distinction between the two! Initially there were no Tomcat at all, just some web config and controllers like `web.xml` and `TestController.java`. It was that I didnt know how to run the project, which - after some googling - somehow led me to tomcat and eventually this mess.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot you don't need a `web.xml`, just a main class and your controllers. All the rest is going to be setup for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hmm currently I think I want to grasp a bit about Spring MVC configuration using xml files before moving on with java class files. So base on your comment, I should rather create a pure Spring MVC project, instead of Spring Boot. Is that correct?

Comment: Don't bother, it doesn't add anything and Java config is preferred. Learning XML doesn't give you an advantages as both XML and Java config doe the same. Next to that you can learn SPring MVC with Spring Boot as well saves you a little setup of the `DispatcherServlet` and a servlet container. So I would strongly suggest don't do that and just pick Spring Boot and start from that.